# Django error: AttributeError at - 'Manager' object has no attribute 'META'

Tags: mysql, django, models, django-managers

I'm using django 1.4, and python 2.7

I'm trying to get data from the MySQL database...
views.py:

```
def myRequests(request):
    #request = ProjectRequest.objects
    response = render_to_response('myRequests.html', {'ProjectRequest': request}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
    return response
```

As soon as I uncomment 'request = ProjectRequest.objects' I get the error:

```
AttributeError at /myRequests/
'Manager' object has no attribute 'META'
```

I'm not defining any new user models so this error makes no sense to me.
Exception location:

```
/{path}/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/context_processors.py in debug, line 35
```

modelsRequest.py:

```
class ProjectRequest(Model):
    reqType = CharField("Request Type", max_length = MAX_CHAR_LENGTH)
    reqID = IntegerField("Request ID", primary_key = True)
    ownerID = IntegerField("Owner ID")
    projCodeName = CharField("Project Code Name", max_length = MAX_CHAR_LENGTH)
    projPhase = CharField("Project Phase", max_length = MAX_CHAR_LENGTH)
    projType = CharField("Project Phase", max_length = MAX_CHAR_LENGTH)
    projNotes = CharField("Project Notes", max_length = MAX_CHAR_LENGTH)
    contacts = CharField("Project Notes", max_length = MAX_CHAR_LENGTH)
    reqStatus = CharField("Status", max_length = MAX_CHAR_LENGTH)
    reqPriority = CharField("Request Priority", max_length = MAX_CHAR_LENGTH)
    reqEstDate = DateTimeField("Request Estimated Complete Date", auto_now_add = True)
    lastSaved = DateTimeField("Last saved", auto_now = True)
    created = DateTimeField("Created", auto_now_add = True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.reqID) + ": " + str(self.reqType)

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'djangoTestApp'
        db_table = 'requests'
```

Any idea what's going on?!

Comment: Can you post your actual models and managers? I suspect the problem is somewhere in there.

Comment: what are my managers?

Comment: You don't appear to have any custom managers, the `ProjectRequest.objects` is a manager, you can customize it and that could cause weird issues like these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a different variable name

```
project_request = ProjectRequest.objects
```

The issue is because of this `context_instance = RequestContext(request)`

It loses context of the  `request` object as it has been overwritten. Hence the issue.

```
def myRequests(request):
    project_request = ProjectRequest.objects
    #Now you have access to request object, 
    # do whatever you want with project_request - 
    response = render_to_response('myRequests.html', {'ProjectRequest': project_request}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
    return response
```

The reason you are getting the error `'Manager' object has no attribute 'META'` is, when you do

```
ProjectRequest.objects
```

the default manager (`objects`) for models `ProjectRequest` is assign to the (overwritten)  local variable `request`.

Comment: thank you sir! I also found out that request = ProjectRequest.objects is wrong. It should be request = ProjectRequest.objects.all()